# caching topmenu.phtml

Tags: cache, time

i have a custom topmenu.phtml that adds a lot of load time to run on every page how can i make it get cached and only regenerate the menu html once a day?
thanks
I tried searching but am getting confused I have CE 1.7.0.2 and my caches (including full page) are enabled here is my Aoe Profiler run details

[image]

Comment: A full page cache would (obviously) cache this for you. If you want to cache the individual phtml file you'll need to write an extension that overrides that block and either loads from cache or renders from the template file.

Comment: thank you for your input the full page cache IS already enabled why is it still taking all that time to load?

Comment: If your FPC is on it will render this page once and store the page's html into a cache file. When you reload the page, it loads that html and sends it as a response instead of parsing the php for the response. This means that if you loaded the page with the profiler open, and during that first load the topmenu took that long to load, the html has been cached and you will see the profiler information with the topmenu taking a long time to load, even if this whole page loaded nearly instantly due to the FPC. Are you noticing pages load quickly after the first load?

Comment: thank you for your time so all those __EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT__ entries (their are about 50 of them and they each take ~10ms to run are not running evrey time i reload the page or go to a new page?

Comment: basically I want that the HTML for the top menu should be stored as a block that is regenerated once a day so magento does not have to create the html from the .PHTML file every time a new page is opened

Comment: It will run once per page it's loaded on to become cached. If you'd like that topmenu block to be cached only once and then shared across all pages, you'll need to modify the code of that phtml file (or overwrite it) to either render and cache itself or just read from that cache.

Comment: how do i render and cache a block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the default catalog.topnav block and an instance of Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu, it's already cached for unlimited time (or until any category changes, thanks to cache tags). This is achieved with setCacheLifetime(false) in the constructor. If not, you can use layout XML to call setCacheLifetime(86400), which sets the lifetime to 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

You can call:-
`Mage::app()->cleanCache(Mage_Core_Block_Template::CACHE_GROUP);`
And this will invalidate all cached template blocks including the top menu.